# Python change a variable's value in one-liner for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a simple problem and I couldn't solve it. I have a list;

```
[9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6]
```

If an element in this list is in `digits`, I want to add 1 to `counter` variable.

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lst = [9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6]
```

Right now I'm doing it with

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lst = [9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6]
counter = 0
for x in lst:
    if x in digits:
        counter += 1
```

I want to write that for loop as one-liner. I tried

```
t = counter += 1 for x in lst if x in digits
```

But not worked as expected. I just stuck, how can I do this?

Comment: @vaultah That is a solution for me yes, but I'm wondering how can I make one-liner loop like `[x for x in lst if x in digits]` and add 1 to counter variable? I tried `counter+=1 for x....` as I wrote in my question but didn't work.

Comment: @vaultah could you write these comments as an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two possible ways:

1. [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
counter = len([x for x in lst if x in digits])
```

2. The function: [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)(function, list) which offers an elegant way to filter out all the elements of a list, for which the function function returns True.

```py
    not_digits = lambda x: x not in digits
    counter = len(filter(not_digits, lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are trying to use a python statement instead of an expression in a list comprehension. This will not work. I think @vaultah provides an excellent solution in his comment.

If you insist on explicit assignment to counter, maybe try `reduce`:

```
if 'reduce' not in globals():
    from functools import reduce

counter = 0

digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lst = [9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6]

counter = reduce(lambda c, d: c + 1 if d in digits else c, lst, counter)
```